# PhpStorm autocomplete not working for TypeScript classes in node_modules

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, webstorm, intellisense

I am working on [TypeScript Standard Library](https://github.com/typescript-standard-library/Core) and I want to distribute it as NPM package as is. It means that package will only contain `.ts` files, without `.d.ts` and `.js`.

PhpStorm does not see such package. Usually it suggest to import classes / interfaces, but for classes defined in `.ts` files located in `node_modules` it doesn't.

I've tried all possible configuration options, but no success.

Comment: Latest phpStorm support using tsc directly. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now it isn't possible to configure **PhpStorm** / **WebStorm** to add the imports automatically without ".d.ts" files. See the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24868

**Update:** In 2017.2.3 you can specify the package in 'include' section and WebStorm will autoimport '.ts' symbols from the packages

Comment: Thank you for your response, Andrey. I've enabled option in `tsconfig.json` file `compilerOptions.declaration = true`. Now compiler also generates `.d.ts` files near the source `.ts`. In this case PhpStorm see my classes and autocomplete / autoimport works properly.

Comment: @AlexChandler I fixed the issue in 2017.2.

Comment: You mean, in new release we can use auto-import for .ts files without .d.ts? Awesome!

Comment: Have you a demo repository? I tried it in my setup with WebStorm 2017.2.3 but can't get it to work.